# Eclipse 4.24 crashing while "Decoration Processing"

Tags: eclipse

Yesterday I have installed Eclipse 4.24. The installation didn't show any problems but when compiling/running my current project it showed strange messages such as "Missing class: old_project". Looking at the command line I remarked yet another old project appearing there. And today morning, Eclipse didn't start correctly but was aborted with a message like "Error in Decoration Processing".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing what exactly you did (which IDE package did you install or upgrade on which OS? via Eclipse Installer? did you install additional plugins and if yes, which?) and without knowing the exact error message, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.